# Eclipse Galileo 32 bit windows trying to run on 64 bit windows?

Tags: jvm, eclipse-3.5

[image]

While trying to run eclipse it gives the above error. Whats the problem?

Comment: Well 1 thing I see is that your eclipse says it requires java version 1.5, and you have version 1.6. Try either getting the old version of JRE and JDK or downloading the newest eclipse and updating jdk and jre before running it?

Comment: @keepitreal and I should chose the version 64 bit only right?

Comment: For java or eclipse? I am running 64 bit windows 7 at home, but I can't recall choosing a bit version for that, actually I know I just installed jdk, jde, and eclipse via the Ninite.com site. But what ever you install for one should be the same for all, so if you choose to get the 64 bit eclipse from the eclipse site, you should go to suns site and get the 64 bit jre and jdk installer as well.

Comment: Actually, that might be your problem, because I just noticed that you are currently using the win32 version of eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse Galileo is not present in 64 bit:( and I currently had jdk and jre downloaded for recent versions i.e 1.6 so do I need to install jdk and jre 1.5 versions and if so 32 bit or 64 bit because my windows is vista 64bit but galileo is 32 bit.

Comment: Then I would try installing the 32 bit java. Why are you using Galileo and not the new version of Eclipse?

Comment: I have to do a project which requires that.

Comment: Hey it worked. I was downloading the 1.5 versions of jdk and jre. It worked with recent versions for 32 bit. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Glad it was a simple fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download 32 bit version of new JRE and JDK :P